# R data frame row names become null after transpose

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

R studio contains a built-in dataframe mtcars, from which we can see the row names

```
> row.names(mtcars)

 [1] "Mazda RX4"           "Mazda RX4 Wag"      
 [3] "Datsun 710"          "Hornet 4 Drive"     
 [5] "Hornet Sportabout"   "Valiant"            
 [7] "Duster 360"          "Merc 240D"          
 [9] "Merc 230"            "Merc 280"           
[11] "Merc 280C"           "Merc 450SE"         
[13] "Merc 450SL"          "Merc 450SLC"        
[15] "Cadillac Fleetwood"  "Lincoln Continental"
[17] "Chrysler Imperial"   "Fiat 128"           
[19] "Honda Civic"         "Toyota Corolla"     
[21] "Toyota Corona"       "Dodge Challenger"   
[23] "AMC Javelin"         "Camaro Z28"         
[25] "Pontiac Firebird"    "Fiat X1-9"          
[27] "Porsche 914-2"       "Lotus Europa"       
[29] "Ford Pantera L"      "Ferrari Dino"       
[31] "Maserati Bora"       "Volvo 142E"
```

When this dataframe is transposed, I expected to see these row names as column names.

> tmtcars <- t(mtcars)

It looks ok, however,

```
> names(tmtcars)

NULL
```

could anyone give me any suggestion why I failed to get the expected names?

Comment: tmtcars is a matrix,  not a data.frame.  You can use `colnames(tmtcars)`  OR make it a data.frame with `tmtcars <- as.data.frame(t(mtcars))`

Comment: Thanks @G5W. So, I know now that after transposing, a dataframe is no longer a dataframe.